# How to extract coordinates from an array of coordinate points

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to find the coordinates of the centroid of the projected image from the SURF example.

The example has an array of points like this : PointF[] pts = new PointF[]
The result of these points are as follows as seen in debugger : 
X1,Y1 - Top Left
X2,Y2 - Top Right
X3,Y3 - Bottom Left
X4,Y4 - Bottom Right

I want to extract the values as int or double so that I can calculate the centroid.
How do I do this?

Comment: What is PointF,  is it just (X,Y)? else could you give the definition?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: what do you mean, how to extract values from an array? use the indexer. you can access the values just the way the debugger shows them.

Comment: Hi,
I used this  string s = string.Join(" ", pts);
this gives me a string of the coordinates like {X1,Y1}, {X2,Y2}....

Comment: With these 4 points it is just the center of rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you have an array of PointF, so you want to access to each coordinates:

IF your array contains 2 elements, you have pts[0] and pts[1], so you could access X and Y like that:

pts[0].X, pts[0].Y and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow your question. [PointF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) has a X and Y properties that are both `float` are you asking how to access them in the array?

```
PointF[] pts = ...
pts[index].X; // this will get you the X value for the PointF at the given index
```

If you have a method the takes `int` or `double` that you want to pass these values to then a simple cast will get you what you need

```
double x = (double)pts[index].X;
```

If there's something else that you don't understand could you elaborate in your question?